# Swift 3 чтение и запись фалов

Tags: ios, swift, файловая-система

Доброго.

Как в 3м свифтет правило сохранять и читать файлы? В частности текстовые.
Вот так пробую (пробую читать текстовый файл заранее расположенный в некой папке от корня проекта, типа assets в андроиде).

```
func readAsset(fileName : String) -> String
{
     let tempDirectoryURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: RootDirectory, isDirectory: true)
    let targetURL = tempDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent( fileName );
    let fileData = NSData.init(contentsOf: targetURL);

    let datastring = NSString(data: fileData as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);

    return (datastring)! as String;

}
```

При присваивании let datastring ловлю ошибку
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Раз до этого присваивания дошло, значит файл есть и данные из него прочитали? Проблема в преобразовании теперь в строку, так понимаю..

Что не так делаю?..

PS: вызываю как  data = readAsset("langs/ru/locale.txt");
в проекте папка langs лежит рядом с ViewController.swift

RootDirectory определена при запуске программы как:

```
    let filemgr = FileManager.default;
    RootDirectory = filemgr.currentDirectoryPath;
```

Comment: Во-первых, что за RootDirectory? И во-вторых, надо инициализировать класс FileManager, через который и работать. Как минимум, прежде чем читать данные стоит убедиться, что файл существует и он является файлом, а не директорией. Рекомендую в целом почитать о файловой системе iOS и macOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: добавил в вопрос уточнение. Ссылку посмотрел. Не понял достоверно, где хранятся добавленные мною в проект файлы. Полагаю что на одном уровне с Documents и Temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Если правильно понял, что вы хотите получить

```
    var data: Data?
    if let pathToFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: nil) {
    data = Data(contentsOfFile: pathToFile)
}
```

Comment: Оно самое! Благодарю!

Comment: я правда слегонца по-другому сделал:
заменил первые 2 строки на одну
        let targetURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "st/"+fileName, withExtension: "");